# Why do annotations been added for PyDev not work?

Tags: python, eclipse, ide

When I use PyDev to add an annotation (such as `@IgnorePep8`) from the "Quick Fix / Content Assistants" the annotation is not added to the document. Other fixes available work.

**What do I need to do to get this working?**

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to first add an inline comment then then trigger the `Quick Fix / Content Assistant`. This will allow the annotation to be added to the line.